# How to set environment variables within ts file on NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am struggling with the following error:

```
error TS2591: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node` and then add 'node' to the types field in your tsconfig.

baseUrl: process.env.TEST
```

// environment.prod.ts

```
import 'dotenv/config';

export const environment = {
    production: true,
      baseUrl: process.env.TEST
    };
```

//.env

```
TEST=whatever
```

I've already installed @types/node and dotenv, the problem is the IDE on typescript files is telling me there is something wrong with *TEST*, what am I missing?

Comment: Seems like your IDE is simply kidding you. If you have installed `dotenv` and `@types/node`, `tsc environment.prod.ts` shouldn't give you any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not enough to install `dotenv` package, it's types and use it right after with `process.env.TEST`

You also have to configure your `dotenv` package in `App.ts` or any root file of an application you have

something like this:

```
dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + `/../.production.env}` })
```

Comment: Excuse me sir, there is no app.ts on my app. also i cannot set the code you told me on environment.ts, thanks

Comment: what's your root file? it can be index.js also

Comment: would you mind to be more explicit with where should I place your code? I think i am doing it properly but it is the first time i am on NodeJS... thank you

Comment: The question is I have to set it on a .ts script. On .js file no problem about it

Comment: what the problem was tho?